# Processed spliced and unspliced count matrices for existing scRNA-seq atlases

Tags: r, python, scrnaseq

Before I do this myself...

Is there any compiled batch-corrected dataset of the major scRNA-seq atlases (Mouse Cell Atlas, Mouse Organogenesis Atlas, Mouse Gastrulation Atlas, Tabula Muris, Tabula Muris Senis, etc.) with processed spliced AND unspliced count matrices?

I would be surprised if there is, but in the event there isn't, are there new pipelines in development that will make processing of raw data easier for studying RNA velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there are preprocessed datasets available, however, [Kallisto + Bustools](https://www.kallistobus.tools/velocity_tutorial.html) was designed specifically for the rapid quantification of spliced and unspliced transcripts.

Comment: I hear there's an even easier pipeline/container in the works that automates Kallisto + Bustools